# Laravel Eloquent ORM relationship representation of tag-user-video

Tags: php, orm, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to achieve the following with relationships in Laravel's Eloquent ORM.

- Global tags are stored in a tags model (e.g. CSS, HTML)
- Users can choose many tags as their 'favourites'
- Videos can have many tags (e.g. CSS, HTML)

From the above, I'd like to be able to show the users favourite videos, based on video tags being related to the tags the user has chosen.

I'd like to be able to show these videos in a list, based on the tags the user has chosen. I'm not sure if I should be using many to many polymorphic relationships. I've already set these up, but at the moment I'm having to loop through tags doing something like the following:

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->tags()->with('videos')->get() as $tag)
    @foreach($tag->videos as $video)
        {{ $video->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Whereas I'd love to be able to do the following:

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->favouriteVideos())
    {{ $video->name }}
@endforeach
```

Bear in mind the above examples are simply testing, and I obviously would be doing the relationship gathering in my controllers.

Perhaps I'm going the wrong way about this, but I'm sure this can be achieved. I simply can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably already found a solution, but for anyone else bumping into this: try using [query scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes).